# Is it possible to run a different amount of replicas on different nodes with Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am running a Docker Swarm on 2 nodes (1 = manager and 1 = worker).
I have the following services:

- PHP-FPM
- Redis
- Nginx Webserver
- MariaDB

I am running a Laravel app that does quite a bit of processing in the background due to many queue workers (Laravel Horizon). It works great.

But what I want is to have for example 2 PHP-FPM replicas running on node2 (host2) and only 1 replica running on node 1 (host1). So in total 3 replicas.
When I simply change `replicas: 3` the 3rd replica **might** appear on node 1 **or** on node2.
But I do NOT want any more PHP-FPM replicas on node1 due to resources because that already has my DB, Redis, webserver running as well.

Currently I have 2 replicas spread accross my 2 nodes.

```
deploy:
      mode: replicated # "global": exactly one container per swarm node; "replicated": a specified number of containers
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        # max_replicas_per_node: 1
        # constraints:
        #  - node.hostname == small-websites-3
        #  - node.role == manager
        preferences:
          - spread: node.hostname == host1
          - spread: node.hostname == host2
```

As you can see in my docker-compose.yml config above I have commented out the placement constraints as they did not achieve what I wanted.
So yeah I hope there is a way to achieve different amounts of replicas per node specified in case of an odd number of replicas as I believe Docker Swarm manages it perfectly fine when I have an even number (ie. 4 replicas would go: 2x on node 1 and 2x on node 2).

I hope this makes sense and is possible (without upgrading my node1 and using an even amount of replicas)?

Comment: Or... do I just limit my CPU per service/replica to let's say half of the host's availability and then just run 2 per node (so 4 in total) and forget about 1 on node1 and 2 on node2? :) But then node2 is still not perfectly in balance as node1 has way more services running

Comment: Swarm does not provide a setting for what you are looking for, You will definitly want to set ressource contraints for cpu/memory to make sure the scheduler understand what sort of ressource usage you are aiming for.